# What Is The Difference Between else and !== In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between `else` and `!==` in JavaScript?

I am beginner in JavaScript and I can't find their difference, for example in this code I expected the text to appear when I enter other days.

```
const day= prompt(`Insert The Day`);
if(day===`monday`){
   console.log(`Pray All Day Long`)
}
else if(day===`tuesday`){
   console.log(`Code All Day Long`)
}
else if(day===`wednesday`){
   console.log(`Meditate All Day Long`)
}
else if(day===`Thursday`){
   console.log(`Design All Day Long`)
}
else if(day!==`monday`){
   console.log(`Why Not Monday?`)
}
else{
   console.log(`Invalid Day`)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help that your code has extra exclamation marks (!) in. You might want to look at [how to format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) so that it is legible.

Comment: You get the text "Why Not Monday?" if you enter other days. What is unclear here?

Comment: i ca not understand what is wrong and these are two different condition in java script

Comment: **If** you mean "Is there a difference between `if (a === 1) { x(); } else { y(); }` and `if (a === 1) { x(); } if (a !== 1) { y(); }`, then yes, there's a difference: `a` gets tested once in the first one, and twice in the second (which can matter if `a` isn't a simple variable reference but rather a function call of some kind, or a complex expression).

Answer (score 1):

These 2 are entirely different operators.

`else` is to be applied after an `if` block, and is run if the condition from the `if` block wasn't met.

`==` is a "loose" equals, which means that values of different types with the same value are considered to be equal. This means that `1 == "1"` will return true, even if `1` is an int and `"1"` is a string.

`===` checks for absolute equality, which means that only values with the same type and value are considered equal. This means that `1 === "1"` is false, but `1 === 1` is true.

`!==` is the opposite of `===`, which means that any value with a different type or value is considered not equal. This means that `1 !== 2` is true, and `1 !== "1"` is as well.